# Merge 2 tables with one common field

Tags: join, merge, hive, union

In HIVE, I want to merge 2 tables (both having 2 columns) with one common Column (Time). The merged table will have 3 columns (common + X + Y).

## Table A

```
| Time  | X     |
|------ |---    |
| 1     | 2     |
| 2     | 1     |
| 3     | 5     |
```

## Table B

```
| Time  | Y     |
|------ |---    |
| 2     | 1     |
| 8     | 6     |
```

## Merged Table:

```
| Time  | X     | Y     |
|------ |---    |---    |
| 1     | 2     | 0     |
| 2     | 1     | 1     |
| 3     | 5     | 0     |
| 8     | 0     | 6     |
```

I've tried `UNION ALL` and `OUTER JOIN`, `OUTER JOIN` works but give me `null` result in Time column.

using `UNION ALL`:

```
CREATE TABLE m AS SELECT * FROM A UNION ALL select * FROM B;
```

I get the following:

> SemanticException 1:89 Schema of both sides of union should match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping, I understood your question correctly.

Please check below query

```
CREATE TABLE M AS SELECT coalesce(A.TIME,B.TIME) TIME , coalesce(A.X,0) as X, coalesce(B.Y,0) as Y
FROM A FULL OUTER JOIN B
ON A.TIME = B.TIME;
```